# Aggregate function with different conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this simple query:

```
SELECT
a.new_funderidname as Funder,
COUNT(a.new_funderidname) as Units
FROM new_dealsheet a
LEFT JOIN salesorder B ON a.new_dsheetid = B.salesorderid
WHERE a.New_PassedToAdmin = 1
GROUP BY a.new_funderidname
ORDER BY Units desc
```

That's fine, but my B table contains another field called maint, I need to also get the counts for those two possible values, something like

```
SELECT
a.new_funderidname as Funder,
COUNT(a.new_funderidname) as Units,
COUNT(a.new_funderidname) **WHERE b.maint=1 as UnitsMaint**,
COUNT(a.new_funderidname) **WHERE b.maint=0 as UnitsNotMaint**
FROM new_dealsheet a
LEFT JOIN salesorder B ON a.new_dsheetid = B.salesorderid
WHERE a.New_PassedToAdmin = 1
GROUP BY a.new_funderidname
ORDER BY Units desc
```

Can I do that within a single query?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use CASE

```
SELECT
a.new_funderidname as Funder,
COUNT(a.new_funderidname) as Units,
sum(case when b.maint=1 then 1 else 0 end ) as UnitsMaint,
sum(case when b.maint=0 then 1 else 0 end ) as UnitsNotMaint,
FROM new_dealsheet a
LEFT JOIN salesorder B ON a.new_dsheetid = B.salesorderid
WHERE a.New_PassedToAdmin = 1
GROUP BY a.new_funderidname 
ORDER BY Units desc
```

Comment: You should change COUNT to SUM. The count will count the row no matter what value is in it. :)

Comment: Mistake,Thanks @SeanLange

Answer (score 1):

If maint is always 0 or 1 you could sum them with `Sum(b.mainnt)` and `Sum(1-b.mainnt)`

```
SELECT
a.new_funderidname as Funder,
COUNT(a.new_funderidname) as Units,
Sum(b.mainnt) as UnitsMaint,
Sum(1 - b.mainnt) as UnitsNotMaint
FROM new_dealsheet a
LEFT JOIN salesorder B ON a.new_dsheetid = B.salesorderid
WHERE a.New_PassedToAdmin = 1
GROUP BY a.new_funderidname 
ORDER BY Units desc
```

You might need to do a cast inside `Sum` if b.mainnt is a `bit` type: e.g. `SUM(cast(b.mainnt as int))` and `SUM(1 - cast(b.mainnt as int))`

Answer (score 0):

You could use  PIVOT function.

```
select Funder,
UNITSMAINT+UNITSNOTMAINT as UNITS,
UNITSMAINT,
  UNITSNOTMAINT 
    from
(
SELECT
a.new_funderidname as Funder,b.Maint
FROM new_dealsheet a
LEFT JOIN salesorder B ON a.new_dsheetid = B.salesorderid
WHERE a.New_PassedToAdmin = 1
)
PIVOT 
   (
    count(b.Maint) 
     For(1 as UNITSMAINT,0 as UNITSNOTMAINT)
   );
```

Refer [Pivot function](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)